# Clean canvas in kivy language

Tags: python, kivy

You can call widget's canvas from kivy language using `canvas[.before|.after]` member like this.

```
<MyWidget>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'mylogo.png'
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

How can I clear the canvas before I put the instructions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Clear`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv_string = '''
<MyWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.1, 0.6, 0.3
        Ellipse:
            size: self.size     
            pos: self.pos
        Clear
        Color:
            rgb: 0.6, 0.2, 0.1
        Ellipse:
            size: self.size     
            pos: self.center
'''

Builder.load_string(kv_string)

class MyWidget(Widget):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

In example above only one ellipse will be drawn since first one gets erased with `Clear` command. You can call it from Python using code like:

```
class SomeWidget(Widget):
    def some_method(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            # ...
```

Comment: Note: I was making things using the python side and `self.canvas.after` instead of just `self.canvas`, so I needed to use `self.canvas.after.clear` and it was working properly

Answer (score 0):

i used

```
Window.clearcolor = (x,y,z,w)
```

and it works... so why use canvas?